# Involuntarily subscribed to insurance against absense

Tags: france, insurance

I've just been told by my company that I was being subscribed to an insurance scheme. The benefit of this scheme is that if I am absent due to sickness for a few days, then I am paid fully for these days. (Note: If I am absent for 4 days or more, then I am already covered by state insurance).

I wouldn't mind this new scheme, but I think the cost is ridiculous; it is equivalent to 10 days salary a year, and in the 11 years of working full time I have missed about 5 days total.

I have been told unequivocally that the scheme is mandatory, and that it is legal for them to inscribe me like this (which I fully believe). I have been unable to find out if my company gets a commission for each employee it inscribes.

So basically I feel like I am getting my pay docked with very little benefit to me. The only way I can think to redress the balance is if I start taking sick days for minor ailments such as colds, headaches etc., but honestly I would be very uncomfortable with this.

Generally I am satisfied with my job and like the work, but I have had disputes with HR before.

Comment: Do you need a doctor note to justify for sick days and be eligible to the insurance? Would there be consequences if you took 10 sick days a year?  If not you may explain to HR/employer that this scheme allow you basically an extra 10 days of vacation and why this is bad for them.

Comment: Are you sure this is legal? Because in Germany it wouldn´t be. And yes, having insight in the insurance industry, you can be sure somebody is getting a nice commission!

Comment: Could you tell us the french term for the insurance scheme ? Are you sure there isn't an "opt-out" option for the insurance ? Also, this question might be off topic here as it is about french work laws

Comment: What is your question? [You should only ask practical, answerable questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on this site, but as it stands, it's very unclear what you're asking in your post. Please have a look at the [help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) to get some tips about [how to ask good questions](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Would you be happy if you got a raise to match those 10 days you get billed for?

Comment: Perhaps you should polish your resume and spend  10 days looking for a new job?

Comment: Or, suggest that, like social security and pensions, the company makes a contribution?

Comment: What happens in France without that insurance if you slip and break an arm at home? Surely you don't just have to starve for the next 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @nvoigt you get fully compensated by the Assurance Maladie, except for the first 3 days. In this case, OP's insurance policy is even reimbursing those 3 days. (Note that you can still call sick for 1 to 3 days, but those days will be deducted from your paid holidays. There is no limit to the number of sick days you can take yearly however)

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick I learned from movie "Unbreakable" with Bruce Willis. I asked for a list of sick day I taken in last three years and used that info when talking about rise.
You can do the same thing - ask about sick days in few last years, talk with your manager, explain to him that:

1. This scheme encourage you to NOT WORK otherwise you will earn less money
2. Is bad for your morale because if you WON'T take sick day you will earn less working the same hours
3. If this scheme is involuntarily you should get the rise to get your pay on the previous level.

On the persona note - talk with your manager that company deciding to sign employees for extra not-law-required expense without their consent is bad for morale. Now some employees may be happy with this insurance but what if company will decide to sign everyone for Ponzi Scheme? I would also ask if the company is pitching some (and if yes how much) to this insurance.

Comment: I'd refrain from posting a generic answer about this question. This is quite specific to french law. In France, this is quite common, and every state employee has that kind of coverage by default (get paid on every sick day from day 1 as long as there is a doctor's note, with no yearly limit)

Comment: This is something different than Assurance maladie.

Comment: Of course. But there is also the mandatory "mutuelle" that every employer must subscribe for their employees. If that's the "mutuelle" that is reimbursing the sick days, there is nothing OP can do. If this is another optional "police d'assurance", then OP can opt out

Comment: I would do the Bruce Willis approach, but do it to ask for a raise to compensate for the loss, since it sounds like there is no getting out of the insurance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:

Start to take sick days for "minor ailments such as colds, headaches etc.".
It is better for you, because you don't have to work when sick.
It is also better for your employer. Presenteeism leads to poorer results for the company, because you don't perform at a 100% while your employer has to pay you fully. There is also the risk that you infect coworkers.

From your wording, I assume you currently come to work sick if you have what you call "minor ailments". You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Certainly don't come into work if you have a contagious disease but a headache doesn't qualify. Nevertheless this does not seem like a good solution, rather a tit-for-tat response that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @Roy not a good solution for whom? The company profits, because instead of getting less than full performance from an employee while they still have to pay the full salary the don't have to pay anything.

Comment: The OP, they clearly state in their question they are uncomfortable with taking days off for minor ailments.